# Calling a New Method from a Different Class in the Same Package

Tags: java, class, methods, package

I am trying to create an application with several tabbed panes, and to keep the code manageable, I wanted to have the content for these panes in separate classes, in separate .java files.

I have 3 files currently
(i) TestLayout.java

```
package testlayout;
public class TestLayout 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        MainFrame mainFrameObject = new MainFrame();
        mainFrameObject.displayMainFrame();
    }
}
```

(ii) MainFrame.java

```
package testlayout;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class MainFrame 
{
    JFrame masterFrame = new JFrame("JAVA 1.1");
    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    public void displayMainFrame()
    {
        masterFrame.setSize(1000, 600);
        masterFrame.setVisible(true);
        masterFrame.setResizable(false);
        masterFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
        masterFrame.add(tabbedPane);

        DisplayReadMe drmObj = new DisplayReadMe();
        drmObj.showReadMe();
        //showReadMe();
    }

    /*
    public void showReadMe()
    {
        JPanel panelReadMe = new JPanel(new GridLayout(10,1,8,8));
        panelReadMe.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));
        tabbedPane.addTab("Read Me", null, panelReadMe, "First Tab");
        String testreadMeTestMessage = "This is a test message";

        JLabel testreadMeLabel = new JLabel(testreadMeTestMessage, SwingConstants.LEFT);
        testreadMeLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.orange,3));
        panelReadMe.add(testreadMeLabel);
    }
    */
}
```

and 
(iii) DisplayReadMe.java

```
package testlayout;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class DisplayReadMe extends MainFrame
{
    public DisplayReadMe()
    {

    }
    public void showReadMe()
    {
        System.out.println("method showReadMe begins");
        JPanel panelReadMe = new JPanel(new GridLayout(10,1,8,8));
        panelReadMe.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));
        tabbedPane.addTab("Read Me", null, panelReadMe, "First Tab");
        String testreadMeTestMessage = "This is a test message";

        JLabel testreadMeLabel = new JLabel(testreadMeTestMessage, SwingConstants.LEFT);
        testreadMeLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.orange,3));
        panelReadMe.add(testreadMeLabel);
        System.out.println("method showReadMe ends");
    }
}
```

My query is, when I uncomment the //showReadMe(); and showReadMe method in MainFrame, it works.  The tab is added to the JFrame and the test message shows in the box.

But should the

```
DisplayReadMe drmObj = new DisplayReadMe();
drmObj.showReadMe();
```

code, not do the same thing?  Am I not calling the showReadMe method from the DisplayReadMe class, akin to showReadMe().

I have tried revalidate, repaint and threading and nothing seems to call the method and show the tab and message ?

Any guidance would be gratefully appreciated
Many Thanks
PG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is actually working, but the *tabbedPane* instance in *drmObj* is different with respect to the *JTabbedPane* class member in *MainFrame*. Try to add *tabbedPane* as a parameter in *showReadMe()* and refer to that instance whenever adding elements. It should work.

*public void showReadMe(JTabbedPane tabbedPane);*

...

*drmObj.showReadMe(this.tabbedPane);*

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you Lorenzo for the quick response.  Your solution worked perfectly. PG

Answer (score 0):

you may not have duplicated method with same parameters, check if you have another showReadMe method who expects nothing as parameter.
if you make an overwrite of the showReadMe, remember that it will make showReadMe of the main class, then will make showReadMe inherited since it cannot go more up.

i donno if i explained it well at all.

Comment: Thank you Joel for the quick response, it was indeed parameter related. PG